# Output matched string through end of tab-indented section?

Tags: linux, class, sed, grep

Sample code from pci.ids below. I want to use the class code from lspci (lets say it's 0580) and have it navigate to C 05 > 80: Memory controller. I feel the most appropriate way (to avoid returning a value from the wrong class) is to just cut the section of C 05 first, then look for 80. Grep -A... will return everything after, and therefore if the 80 doesn't match something in C05 it would jump down to some Cn which contains an 80 element.

```
C 03  Display controller
    00  VGA compatible controller
        00  VGA controller
        01  8514 controller
    01  XGA compatible controller
    02  3D controller
    80  Display controller
C 04  Multimedia controller
    00  Multimedia video controller
    01  Multimedia audio controller
    02  Computer telephony device
    03  Audio device
    80  Multimedia controller
C 05  Memory controller
    00  RAM memory
    01  FLASH memory
    80  Memory controller
C 06  Bridge
    00  Host bridge
    01  ISA bridge
    02  EISA bridge
    03  MicroChannel bridge
    04  PCI bridge
        00  Normal decode
        01  Subtractive decode
    05  PCMCIA bridge
```

Comment: I figure I could iterate through each element and stop at an instance of 'C ' but there's gotta be a more appropriate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass "0580" into the awk program:

```
awk -v value='0580' '
    BEGIN {a = substr(value,1,2); b = substr(value,3,2)} 
    $1 == "C" { p = ($2 == a)} 
    p && $1 == b {print; exit}
' file
```

If the first word is "C", set a boolean to true if the second word is "05".
If the flag is true and the first word is "80", print the current line and exit.

Comment: This works well under the assumption that the specified class will include the code (in this case, Class 5 will include element 80). However, I'm trying to find a way to make it break in the event of it not existing. Your code, for example, will find the next instance of "80" if there is no "80" within Class 5. I need it to break instead.

Comment: Update should address that concern. If there's no "80" in "c05", it won't print. It will run through the whole file though.

Comment: This helped, thanks! On a similar note, how would you go about doing the following: assume that instead of C 05 it was just 05. So the first, non-indented line for each class was just some random number which may or may not = a number of a sub element. How would you go about the section titles (in this class C 01, C 02, etc.) without assuming the name of the non-indented line? Pseudocode logic would be: if(!startsWithWhitespace); print. If you want a reference, I'm using a pci.ids file which has a lot of random stuff I don't need. My task now is to search a vendor ID# and return the vendor.

Comment: Found a solution to that: grep -v '^\s'

Comment: Back to the original question, how can I manipulate this to work for any words in this format? In other words, if I have: 8086 Intel Corporation (unindented) then within it elements: 8086 a \n 8086 b \n etc. how can I just return everything within the un-indented 8086 Intel field?

Comment: Please ask a new question